# Semantic UI CSS is not working on my website

Tags: css, semantic-ui

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test | Imploxia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <button class="ui button">
  Follow
</button>
```

Any reason why on my website it is just appearing as plain CSS and no Semantic in there?

Comment: Do you have those `semantic/dist/*` files on your web server? Look at your browser's Network panel to see if they are being loaded (200 response code).

Answer (score 2):

The link to `semantic.min.css` and possibly `semantic.min.js` is incorrect

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test | Imploxia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <button class="ui button">
  Follow
</button>
```